# get a table without weekend and holidays. MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have been written two tables already. First one is all the date in a year named time_dimension and second one named tbl_holidays are public holidays in this year. However, i want to get the day without both weekends and holidays. the query i wrote is like；

```
SELECT ti.id, ti.db_date, ti.year, ti.month, ti.day, ti.quarter, ti.week,   ti.day_name, ti.month_name
FROM time_dimension ti
LEFT JOIN  tbl_holidays tb on ti.db_date=tb.startdate
where  day_name in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday');
```

can anyone help me to get rid of the holidays table in this query?

Update the answer:

```
SELECT ti.id, ti.db_date, ti.year, ti.month, ti.day, ti.quarter, ti.week, ti.day_name, ti.month_name
FROM DeJuMa.time_dimension ti
LEFT JOIN  tbl_holidays tb on ti.db_date=tb.startdate
where  day_name in ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday')
AND ti.db_date NOT IN (select startdate from tbl_holidays tb );
```

Comment: `AND ti.db_date NOT IN (date1, date2, ...)`.

Comment: the problem solved. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude holidays:

```
SELECT *
FROM time_dimension ti
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_holidays WHERE startdate = ti.db_date)
    AND day_name IN ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday');
```

Comment: by the way, how to count the date without holidays and weekends after this query?

Comment: Just replace `*` with `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT ti.id, ti.db_date, ti.year, ti.month, ti.day, ti.quarter, ti.week, ti.day_name, ti.month_name
        FROM time_dimension ti WHERE day_name NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
        AND ti.db_date NOT IN (SELECT startdate FROM tbl_holidays);
```

Comment: by the way, how to count the date without holidays and weekends after this query?

Comment: yes i tried count. it works. just thought if any other methods

Comment: Just remove all columns and replace by `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`

Comment: `COUNT` is the fastest way :) so don't give yourself a problem , you have to maximize SQL built-in functions :)